# GPU Memory Management in OpenGL and DirectX 12

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, gpu, directx-12

I am currently improving my knowledge in OpenGL and DirectX 12 in order to create graphics applications with both APIs. I studied several tutorials but I still do not completely understand, how the memory is managed on the GPU side.

In OpenGL (my application runs an OpenGL 3.3 context), the frame buffers are created implicitly so I assume, that they are also freed implicitly by the API. In my example program, I created vertex and index buffers using `glGenBuffers` and uploaded them to the GPU using `glBufferData`. In case I want to update my vertex buffer every frame, I could simply do this using `glBufferSubData`. Let's assume instead, that I want to re-upload my vertex buffer every frame using `glBufferData`. According to the OpenGL documentation, this function creates and initializes the buffer's data store on the GPU. So I assume, that the GPU memory, mapped to this VBO is reused after another call to `glBufferData` in the next frame.

In DirectX 12, the frame buffers must be created by the graphics programmer. Those are managed and reused by the swap chain during the life time of the program. In my DirectX 12 test program, I also create vertex and index buffers using upload heaps and the `ID3D12Device::CreateCommittedResource` function. I also do this every frame for testing purposes. The buffers are stored in `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12Resource>` variables. At the end of the render method, the use count of those buffer pointers should hit `0`, which will free the memory behind on the CPU side. Nevertheless, I do not understand, what happens to the data and the underlying heap on the GPU side. Are they released, whenever the buffer pointer's use count hits `0`, do they need to be freed manually, are they discarded by the GPU when reaching the fence or none of them.

I would really appreciate it, if you could provide some clarifications on this topic and my assumptions.

Can you also please provide an explanation, if and how GPU data needs to be freed by the graphics programmer.

Best regards.

Comment: Buffer objects and "frame buffer"s are different things.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I know that they are different but both of them are used to reference or manage CPU memory I think. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DirectX 12, it uses the same lifetime model as previous versions of Direct3D: The object is kept alive until the reference count hits 0. It's then eligible for destruction. The exact time of cleanup is up to the driver/runtime as it typically does 'delayed destruction' (it actually has both an 'internal' and 'external' reference count, and both have to be 0 before it's really eligible for destruction).

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).

> You should watch [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnYVSP9QgNM) video if you want an overview of the underlying details.